# Error "One or more Extensions in the Add-on failed to run. Contact the developer(s) of the Extension(s) to have this issue resolved.... "

Tags: ecl, sites-9.5, add-on

We have an Add-on package (a ZIP file) that contains a manifest file, configuration, and External Content Library (ECL) Provider-related DLL files as per guidelines from SDL docs.
https://docs.rws.com/816112/782949/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/add-ons-feature
https://docs.rws.com/816112/750864/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/basic-structure-of-the-add-on-manifest-file

We are uploading this package to CMS (Tridion 9.5) through Add On service but received the below error

```
One or more Extensions in the Add-on failed to run. Contact the developer(s) of the Extension(s) to have this issue resolved
Can not initialize add-on. (Environment: cmSites, Client Identity: IP-A***B, Process: TcmBatchProcessor)
Can not initialize add-on. (Environment: cmSites, Client Identity: IP-A***B, Process: TcmServiceHost)
Can not initialize add-on. (Environment: cmSites, Client Identity: IP-A***B, Process: Tridion.TranslationManager.Service)
Can not initialize add-on. (Environment: cmSites, Client Identity: IP-A***A, Process: TcmPublisher)
Can not initialize add-on. (Environment: cmSites, Client Identity: IP-***CB, Process: TcmWorkflowAgent)
Can not initialize add-on. (Environment: cmSites, Client Identity: IP-***9A, Process: TcmServiceHost)
Can not initialize add-on. (Environment: cmSites, Client Identity: IP-A***CB, Process: TcmSearchIndexer)
Can not initialize add-on. (Environment: cmSites, Client Identity: IP-A***B, Process: w3wp)
```

Has anyone experienced similar issues? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update1:**

Manifest.json:

```
{ 
"manifestVersion": "1.0", 
"version": "1.0.0.0-release", 
"id": "CloudinaryProvider", 
"author": "my company", 
"description": "Cloudinary ECL Provider by company", 
"name": "Cloudinary Provider" 
}
```

Comment: What's in the Event log on the server running Addon service and CM server?

Comment: Can you share the manifest file and configuration and mask your configuration if there is any sensitive information? can you also update the event logs?

Comment: Event log:
Error:
Windows cannot load the extensible counter DLL ASP.NET_2.0.50727. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the Windows error code.
Windows cannot load the extensible counter DLL ASP.NET_64_2.0.50727. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the Windows error code.

Warning:
(CertificateServicesClient-AutoEnrollment) for local system with Thumbprint 9d *** is about to expire or already expired.

Comment: Manifest.json:
{
  "manifestVersion": "1.0",
  "version": "1.0.0.0-release",
  "id": "CloudinaryProvider",
  "author": "my company",
  "description": "Cloudinary ECL Provider by company",
  "name": "Cloudinary Provider"
}

Comment: "configuration": {"CloudinaryProvider": {"configuration": {"@xmlns#clp": "ecl:CloudinaryProvider", "bynder#PrivilegedUserName": "uname",
    "bynder#CloudName": "cloudname",
    "bynder#ApiKey": "7****",
    "bynder#ApiSecret": "2*************",
    "bynder#UploadUrl": "http://domain/url",
    "bynder#CoreServiceUrl": "http://domain/url ",
    "bynder#UserName": "uname",
    "bynder#Password": "password",
    "bynder#PageSize": "500"
   },
   "namespaces": {
    "cloudinary": {
     "displayName": "Cloudinary",
     "stubFolders": ["tcm:12-**-*"]
 "sitesCm": {isEnabled": true}

Comment: @Kamaldeen , do you have all the prerequisites installed properly for add-on services .NET Core Runtime version 2.2 etc refer link https://docs.rws.com/816098/796524/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-prerequisites/add-ons-feature-prerequisites  and also if you are running the add-on using https , the error states Thumbprint 9d *** is about to expire or already expired please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65276673/warning-certificateservicesclient-autoenrollment-in-event-viewer

Comment: @Kamaldeen, Please update your config information in the question as I updated, still I see some sections of the configs that are missing. please remove your config comments from here

Comment: And what's in the ECL log file? (Please update the question rather than responding in comment)